# Nutch 1.12 regex url filter unable to form regex

Tags: regex, solr, web-crawler, nutch

The content of my seed.txt is `https://www.drugs.com` and I want to crawl pages with structure as

> https://www.drugs.com/cdi/**uniqueDrugName**.html

**Example of pages that I want to crawl are**

1. `https://www.drugs.com/cdi/acetaminophen.html`
2. `https://www.drugs.com/cdi/refludan.html`
3. `https://www.drugs.com/cdi/Erbitux.html`
4. `https://www.drugs.com/cdi/ontak.html`

where I want to crawl a few of these drugs' pages.
please suggest how or what regex I should use as I am a novice in regex. Thankyou.

I have tried the following regex but they don't work

```
+^https://([a-z0-9]*\.)*drugs\.com/cdi/([a-z0-9]*\.)*html
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `+` at the begining of your regex?

Comment: @ltux `+` is required to let nutch know that the urls satisfying this expression need to be accepted and the urls satisfying expressions starting with a `-` should be ignored. For **example** see [link](https://github.com/kinow/nutch/blob/master/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt.template)

Comment: I am also facing similar issue , have posted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497690/nutch-not-crawling-urls-except-the-one-specified-in-seed-txt but no response yet.Please let me know if you are able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't entirely clear what you want, but I've made a few corrections to your regex. It now matches your example.

`(?m)^https:\/\/.*drugs\.com\/cdi\/.*\.html`

- `(?m)` makes sure that `^` will work.
- The `/` characters have been escaped.
- There is no need to use `[a-z0-9]*`. I have replaced this with `.*`.

If this is not what you want, please edit your question to include some more examples and notify me in the comments.

Comment: Sorry it didn't change the result. Also a `+` inplace of `(?m)` is required to let nutch know that this expression (the one starting with a `+`) should be crawled and an exp. starting with `-` needs to be ignored. See [this](https://github.com/kinow/nutch/blob/master/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt.template)

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A3._Crawl_your_first_website) `+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/` would be used if you wish to limit the crawl to the `nutch.apache.org` domain