# Nutch not crawling URLs except the one specified in seed.txt

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Apache Nutch 1.12 and the URLs I am trying to crawl is something like https://www.mywebsite.com/abc-def/ which is the only entry in my seed.txt file. Since I don't want any page to be crawl that doesn't have "abc-def" in the URL so I have put the following line in regex-urlfilter.txt :

```
+^https://www.mywebsite.com/abc-def/(.+)*$
```

When I try to run the following crawl command :

```
**/bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://mysolr:3737/solr/coreName $NUTCH_HOME/urls/ $NUTCH_HOME/crawl 3**
```

It crawl and index just one seed.txt url and in 2nd iteration it just say:

```
Generator: starting at 2017-02-28 09:51:36

Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.

Generator: filtering: false

Generator: normalizing: true

Generator: topN: 50000

Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...

Generate returned 1 (no new segments created)

Escaping loop: no more URLs to fetch now
```

When I change the regex-urlfilter.txt to allow everything(+.) it started indexing every URL on https://www.mywebsite.com which certainly I don't want.

If anyone happen to have the same problem, please share how you get past it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got that working after trying multiple things in last 2 days.Here is the solution:

Since the website I was crawling was very heavy, the property in nutch-default.xml was truncating it to 65536 bytes(default).The links I wanted to crawl unfortunately didn't get included in the selected part and hence nutch wasn't crawling it.When I changed it to unlimited by putting the following values in nutch-site.xml it starts crawling my pages :

```
<property>
  <name>http.content.limit</name>
  <value>-1</value>
  <description>The length limit for downloaded content using the http://
  protocol, in bytes. If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer
  than it will be truncated; otherwise, no truncation at all. Do not
  confuse this setting with the file.content.limit setting.
  </description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to tweak properties available in conf/nutch-default.xml. maybe control the number of outlinks your want or modify fetch properties. If you decide to overwrite any property, copy that info to conf/nutch-site.xml and put new value there.

Comment: Could you please be more specific which property should I tweak to make this work. I have already tried few by copying them to nutch-site.xml but it didn't work.

Comment: so basically you don't want to crawl any external link on https://www.mywebsite.com/abc-def/, right? If so, try with setting value of `<name>db.ignore.external.links</name>` as `true`? Let me know and I can edit answer accordingly.

Comment: No, I wanted internal links that have the path starting from mywebsite.com/abc-def/. Anyways, I think I got the resolution of the issue.Thanks for the help.

Comment: sure, may be share the solution you are using?